# C# Static property in non-static class as indicator of main object of this class

Tags: c#, static, coding-style

I have class Important and some objects of this class created. I want allow user to choose main object of this class. Have a look at code below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Important imp1 = new Important("Important 1");
       Important imp2 = new Important("Important 2");
       Important imp3 = new Important("Important 3");

       imp2.SetMostImportant();

       Console.Write(Important.MostImportant.Name);
    }

    public class Important
    {
        public Important(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            if(MostImportant == null)
                SetMostImportant();
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public static Important MostImportant { get; private set; }

        public void SetMostImportant()
        {
            MostImportant = this;
        }
    }
 }
```

Is it good solution? If not, please tell me why not.

Before, to achieve this kind of things I just created boolean field named e.g. IsMainObject and, when I wanted to change main object, I iterated through all objects (or group of object) of specific class except element that I want to be main, and changed boolean to false, in my new candidate I simply set flag to true. Example below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Important imp1 = new Important("Important 1");
       Important imp2 = new Important("Important 2");
       Important imp3 = new Important("Important 3");
       List<Important> list = new List<Important> { imp1, imp2, imp3 };

       foreach(var item in list.Where(x => x.Name != "Important 2"))
       {
           item.SetMostImportant(false);
       }

       imp2.SetMostImportant(true);
       Console.Write(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MostImportant == true).Name);
    }

    public class Important
    {
        public Important(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public bool MostImportant { get; private set; }

        public void SetMostImportant(bool val)
        {
            MostImportant = val;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution because:

1. I don't know if `MostImportant` is true for more than one objects without iterating.
2. I need to write extra-code to handle much more cases.
3. I don't have possibility to always iterate through all instances of specific class (groups not always are enough).

... and much more, but you got the idea.

Comment: There really isn't a way to judge if it's good or bad without context of the business or technical problem that you're trying to solve.  Does that code achieve what you want it to achieve?  Then it's at least good enough on that merit alone.  Can it be improved?  Probably yes, but it depends on answering the question improving in what aspect?  This would also be subject to wide opinion-based answers due to lack of specificity in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Important MostImportant { get; private set; }
```

is a fine solution, and much better than

```
public bool MostImportant { get; private set; }
```

It's not uncommon to have a static property of the type that it's inside of when implementing "singleton" classes. I've written code that resembles this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Instance { get; private set; }
    public MyClass()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("MyClass already instantiated.");
        }
    }
}
```